# Tornado websockets supporting binary part 2

Tags: python, websocket, tornado

I am attempting to pass binary data over websockets, more specifically compressed strings over websockets. In my current setup I use tornado as the server with a [websocket](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/websocket-client/) client transmitting the binary data. The binary data is formed by compressing the data with `zlib`. Both client and server are as simple as they get and are shown below.

Server:

```
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WebSocketServer(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'OPEN'

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'len = {}'.format(len(message))
        print 'GOT MESSAGE: {}'.format(message.decode('zlib'))

    def on_close(self):
        print 'CLOSE'

app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', WebSocketServer)
    ])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(9500)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Client:

```
import websocket

host = 'localhost'
port_ws = 9500
ws = websocket.create_connection('ws://{}:{}/'.format(host, port_ws))
message = 'this is my message'.encode('zlib')
print 'Length of message is {}'.format(len(message))
ws.send(message)
```

The client does not throw any errors, it prints out that the message: `Length of message is 24`. The message is encoded as a `str` as per the zlib standard. The server on the other end does not show that it received any messages, it just understands that a client had connected, and then disconnected. Does anyone know where the problem is? I am not sure if the problem lays within tornado or the websockets library. Any suggestions?

---

EDIT: In response to the comment below (@plg), I modified the scripts above to show that:

1. Non-encoded messages can be send from client to the tornado server
2. Tornado can reply with an encoded message

Server:

```
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class WebSocketServer(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        print 'OPEN'

    def on_message(self, message):
        print 'len = {}'.format(len(message))
        print 'GOT MESSAGE: {}'.format(message)
        self.write_message(message.encode('zlib'))

    def on_close(self):
        print 'CLOSE'

app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/', WebSocketServer)
    ])
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
http_server.listen(9500)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Client:

```
import websocket

host = 'localhost'
port_ws = 9500
ws = websocket.create_connection('ws://{}:{}/'.format(host, port_ws))
#message = 'this is my message'.encode('zlib')
message = 'this is my message'
print 'Length of message is {}'.format(len(message))
ws.send(message)
assert ws.recv().decode('zlib') == message
```

The system works just fine. The assert does not throw an error. The decoded message matches the send message. So I guess there is a problem with either:

1. Sending an encoded message from the client
2. Tornado receiving encoded messages

To be quite honest, I do believe that the first option is more probable than tornado. In my opinion, I believe tornado would alert me if an incoming message is not properly decoded as per the websocket standard. Any more suggestions?

---

EDIT: More development on who is at fault. Instead of using my own server to relay back and fourth my connection, I relayed the connection to `ws://echo.websocket.org/`. My testing application is as shows:

```
import websocket

host = 'localhost'
port_ws = 9500
ws = websocket.create_connection('ws://echo.websocket.org/')
message = 'this is my message'
ws.send(message.encode('zlib'))
got = ws.recv().decode('zlib')
print 'GOT: {}'.format(got)
assert got == message
```

This actually passed the test, the data was received just fine. So I guess there is something wrong with tornado receiving the data?

Comment: Did you try doing it the other way around to see if it works or throws an exception? Using ws.recv() in the client and in open(): self.write_message('this is my message'.encode('zlib')). Also, did you try without the zlib compression, again just in case there's something we're missing.

Comment: @plg It works the other way around. I sent a standard ascii message to tornado, and tornado replied with the message encoded. So that direction works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking though the source code of the `websocket` library, I found that by default it is formatting the packets as text. By changing the line:

```
ws.send('message')
# to:
ws.send('message', opcode=websocket.ABNF.OPCODE_BINARY)
# or better yet:
ws.send_binary('message')
```

The packet will be sent over just fine. Tornado I guess was just ignoring the fake binary packets since they were marked as text and contained binary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [commit](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/308) tornado supports websocket compression extensions.